# Do function expressions - as well as function statements - get pushed onto the call-stack?

Tags: javascript

Watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) that teaches about the call-stack, the examples it gives for functions that get pushed onto the stack are all function declarations. Do function expressions enter the callstack as well?

If not, is that why function declarations are described as hoisted? For example the 'main' function (the .js file) tries to be executed, and the computer notices some expressions and statements and loops - and amongst this a function declaration. This function declaration is put 'ontop' of the the main function and must execute before the main function has a chance to.